# Ошибка в SQL запросе при добавлении записи PDO

Tags: mysql, sql, pdo

```
if (!empty($_POST['message']) && !empty($_POST['user_name']))
{
    $name = $_POST['user_name'];
    $text = $_POST['message'];
    $product = (is_numeric($_POST['product']) && !empty($_POST['product'])) ? $_POST['product']:NULL;
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `user277145_jess`.`otzivi` (`id`, `name`, `text`, `product`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, ':name', ':text', :product, ".time().";";
    //die($sql);
    $resutl = $mysql->query($sql, [':name'=> $name, ':text' => $text, ':product' => $product]);
}
```

Вот ошибка:

> SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 1

Можете мне пальцем ткнуть где ошибка у меня ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Вам не нужно обрамлять параметры апострофами
2. Вам нужно закрыть скобку после `VALUES`

```php
$sql = "INSERT INTO `user277145_jess`.`otzivi` (`id`, `name`, `text`, `product`, `time`) VALUES (NULL, :name, :text, :product, ".time().");";
```

Comment: Спасибо, заработало, только теперь вылезла другая: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2053

Comment: public function query($sql, $params=[])
  {
   try {
    $sth = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $sth->execute($params);
    return $sth->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
    
   } catch (PDOException $e) {
    die('<b>Ошбика при выполнение запроса QUERY</b>:   ' . $e->getMessage());
   }
  }

Comment: @cr1gger Если мой ответ решил Вашу проблему, отметьте его как правильный. Если у Вас есть новые вопросы, то создайте новую тему

Comment: ну ты и злодей...

Comment: @cr1gger Я не злодей. Этот ресурс предназначен для того, чтобы другие люди могли находить здесь ответы